# Instantiate, merge map in groovy

Tags: groovy

I normally need to create a nested maps in groovy.
For that I have to usually check if the desired key is already present or not and then create if required. Also I need to merge maps.

Somehow I feel this:

```
def map1 = [:]
map1 << ["key1" : ["atr1" : "val1"]]

         //after some code

map1 << ["key1" : ["atr2" : "val2"]]

         //after some code

map1 << ["key1" : ["atr1" : "val3"]]
println map1
```

should print this:

```
[key1:[atr1:val3, atr2:val2]]
```

But it prints just:

```
[key1:[atr1:val3]]
```

For that I need to do:

```
def map1 = [:]
if(!map1["key1"])
    map1["key1"] = [:]
map1["key1"] << ["atr1" : "val1"]

    //after some code

if(!map1["key1"])
    map1["key1"] = [:]
map1["key1"] << ["atr2" : "val2"]

    //after some code

if(!map1["key1"])
    map1["key1"] = [:]
map1["key1"] << ["atr1" : "val3"]
```

Is there any way to eliminate:

```
if(!map1["key1"])
   map1["key1"] = [:]
```

may be using safe navigation operator-like stuff, implicitly check for null and instantiate

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `Map::withDefault`, and then using leftShift `<<` to add new entries:

```
def map1 = [:].withDefault { [:] }
map1["key1"] << ["atr1" : "val1"]

         //after some code

map1["key1"] << ["atr2" : "val2"]

         //after some code

map1["key1"] << ["atr1" : "val3"]

assert map1 == [key1:[atr1:'val3',atr2:'val2']]
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to override `leftShift` for an instance of `Map`?

Comment: @Opal no idea. In my very little experience maps are kinda clumsy to metaclass.